# onTouch and onTouchEvent methods in Android

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouch

I wrote like below with 'onTouch' method.

But 'getPointerCount()' and 'getAction()' spits out the same values all the time.

This code can't recognize multi-touch.

And 'onTouch' method isn't called when MotionEvent.ACTION_UP occurs.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    relativelayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

    relativelayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.i("test", "multiTouchCount : " + event.getPointerCount());
            Log.i("test", "action : " + event.getAction());
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

So, I tried the same thing with onTouchEvent method and this works.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    Log.i("test", "multiTouchCount : " + event.getPointerCount());
    Log.i("test", "action : " + event.getAction());

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

What's the problem with 'onTouch' method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `onTouch()` method of the Listener, you unconditionally return `false`, which causes the View to no longer receive touch events after the first `ACTION_DOWN` event, until `ACTION_DOWN` happens again.

If you want to ensure that the View will continuously receive multi-touch events, return `true` unconditionally.

Comment: Both of the return statements are auto generated codes, and OnTouchListener is an interface so I can't call super method

Comment: Ok, I'll try with 'true'

Comment: No problem! In answer your first comment, the IDE's auto-generated code isn't always going to be exactly what you need in every circumstance. It's just pasting pre-defined code blocks, and you may very well need to change things to suit your situation. Anyway, cheers!

Comment: Oh, yeah, good point about the interface. Don't know what I was thinking.